# How to fix HTML/CSS/JQuery sidebar - content should be hidden until selected

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which works just fine, with the exception of:

- When I click the open in the sidebar, it should show only that
  material ("Click on 'Charts' should show Charts material). I should not be able to scroll down the page and see everything.
- When an option from the sidebar is selected, it should be highlighted (`class="active"`) so that you know which page you're on.

If there's a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Side Navigation Bar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".hamburger").click(function(){
                          $(".wrapper").toggleClass("active")
                        })
                });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="top_navbar">
                <div class="logo"><a>Demonstration</a></div>

                <div class="top_menu">
                        <div class="home_link"><a href="#"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span><span>Home</span></a>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_body">

                <div class="sidebar_menu">
                <div class="inner__sidebar_menu">

                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#top" class="active"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-border-all"></i></span>      <span class="list">Dashboard</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#chart">   <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i></span>       <span class="list">Charts</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i></span>    <span class="list">Contact</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></span>    <span class="list">About</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">        <span class="icon"><i class="fab fa-blogger"></i></span>         <span class="list">Blogs</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i></span>  <span class="list">Maps</span></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="hamburger">
                                <div class="inner_hamburger">
                                        <span class="arrow">
                                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i>
                                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
                                        </span>
                                </div>
                        /div>

                </div>
                </div>

        <a name="dash" id="dash">
            <div class="container">
                        <div><h1>Dashboard</h1></div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a name="chart" id="chart">
            <div class="container">
                        <div><h1>Charts</h1></div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                            <div class="item">Chartum ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum omnis nihil aut aperiam adipisci suscipit ullam sunt saepe cupiditate quam distinctio officiis tempore laudantium, animi amet corrupti ratione est commodi! Sunt tempora quod magnam optio, reiciendis veritatis, necessitatibus eos molestias facilis reprehenderit maiores ipsum quaerat placeat laborum, a aspernatur corporis.</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Subrayada|Ubuntu:400,500,700&display=swap');

* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
}

body {
        background: #e8edf5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .logo {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #3421C0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #22119d;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .logo a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px 0;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
        height: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0 40px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu .home_link a {
        display: block;
        background: #3421C0;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu .home_link a:hover,
.wrapper .top_navbar .right_info .icon_wrap:hover  {
        background: #5343c7;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .right_info {
        display: flex;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .right_info .icon_wrap {
        padding: 8px 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #3421C0;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 65px;
        left: 0;
        background: #3421C0;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu .inner__sidebar_menu {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 60px;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu ul li a {
        color: #7467d3;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 20px 35px;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu ul li a .icon {
        margin-right: 8px;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu ul li a span {
        display: inline-block;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu ul li a:hover {
        background: #5343c7;
        color: #fff;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu ul li a.active {
        background: #22119d;
        color: #fff;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu .hamburger {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: -25px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #e8edf5;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu .inner_hamburger,
.main_body .sidebar_menu .hamburger .arrow {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu .inner_hamburger {
        width: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 40px;
        background: #3421C0;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu .hamburger .arrow {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
}

.main_body .sidebar_menu .hamburger  .fa-long-arrow-alt-right {
        display: none;
}

.main_body .container {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
        margin-top: 65px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        padding: 25px 40px;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.main_body .container .item_wrap {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main_body .container .item_wrap .item {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        padding: 25px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 22px;
}

.main_body .container .item_wrap .item:first-child {
        margin-right: 20px;
}

        /* after adding active class */
.wrapper.active .sidebar_menu {
        width: 100px;
}

.wrapper.active .hamburger .fa-long-arrow-alt-right {
        display: block;
}

.wrapper.active .hamburger .fa-long-arrow-alt-left {
        display: none;
}

.wrapper.active .sidebar_menu ul li a .list {
        display: none;
}

.wrapper.active .main_body .container {
        width: calc(100% - 100px);
        margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your user click the "Click on Charts" button, it should redirect to a seperate page, because in the same page, the user will always be able to scroll.

If you want to highlight the option that is being clicked, you need to use the onclick event listener, and create a global variable that stores the toggle state.

Example code:

```
const Links = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-links") //sidebar links
for (let link = 0; link < Links.length; link++)
{
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
        //check global state
    })
}
```